# Visual Studio How To Check if all public members of Class are defined in Interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Is there a tool or a Analysis possiblity in Visual Studio that could find the public memebrs (methods, fields, properties) of a Class who are not defined in the Interface of that Class. This would be a good help I would like to have for my code reviews.

Comment: not sure, but you can open the Class tree of other interface and class and compare it manually.

Comment: you want to know which method unused in you code ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand you: public members _are_ the interface of the class, so by definition you won't find any which are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make sure that all of you public members are defined in your Interface, you can use Visual Studio's capability of extracting an interface and compare it to your interface.

You can do this by:

1. Right-Clicking on the class name
2. Refactor
3. Select "Extract Interface"

I also recommend using [FxCop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FxCop)(can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6544)) for your code analysis. It also has a [plugin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d3b1c20f-92b1-44b5-ae63-92605c99757c) for integrating in Visual studio.

[image]

Comment: This is already very nice. Now if we could automate this and have and automated compare tool with log...

Answer (score 1):

if you want to find unused cod than use ReSharper.

Right click on your solution and selection "Find Code Issues". One of the results is "Unused Symbols". This will show you classes, methods, etc., that aren't used.

or

FxCop, which is built into higher editions of Visual Studio, will warn of unused private or internal members. Right-click your project and choose Run Code Analysis. In conjunction with "unreachable code segments" being identified by the compiler as others have noted, this should catch the remaining unused code.

[Find Dead Code](http://devonenote.com/2010/03/find-dead-code/)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [NDepend](http://ndepend.com/). It is a static code analysis tool with a Code Query Language to check every possible aspect of the code.